# How can I type this letter づ

Tags: discussion

when typing "dzu" on japanese IME, it doesn't work :/

Answer (score 28, accepted):

I used to have the same problem. You just need to type "du" instead.

Comment: Me too! Writing romaji in Japanese dictionaries search field used to be a pain in the neck because of this problem.

Comment: You missed the chance of giving a technically correct, informative and useful answer with only two letters =)